# How to Load Component Services/DCOM Config SnapIn

Tags: powershell, dcom, pssnapin

I have a PS script to do some DCOM configuration. It works fine as long as I have the Component Services/DCOM Config snapin loaded. I want to load that programmatically so I can do all of this as part of an install package. Does anyone know how to do it? I don't know the name of the snapin to add/import.

To load the snapin I run comexp.msc -32 and click Component Services, Computers, My Computer, DCOM Configuration.
Thanks

Comment: _"It works fine as long as I have the Component Services/DCOM Config snapin loaded"_ - how are you doing this?

Comment: I added details to question above.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. I couldn't find a way of loading  Component services on the DCOM Config spapIn. But I found a workaround to add the user the Default DCOM Launch and Activation permissions using this powershell script:

https://www.peppercrew.nl/index.php/2012/03/set-dcom-remote-access-via-powershell/

That way, you don't need to assign the user to that particular DCOM App.

Hope this help

This is the powershell script:

```
   PARAM(
    [string]$Principal = $(throw "`nMissing -Principal DOMAIN\Group"),
    $Computers = $(throw "`nMissing -Computers ('server01','server02')"))

# USAGE:
# .\Set-RemotePermission-DCOM.ps1 -Principal "DOMAIN\" -Computers ('', '',...)
#
# EXAMPLE:
# .\Set-RemotePermission-DCOM.ps1 -Principal "DOMAIN\LG-Citrix-Admins" -Computers ('CTX_DC001', 'CTX_DC002')
#
# Inspired by Karl Mitschke's post:
# http://unlockpowershell.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/script-remote-dcom-wmi-access-for-a-domain-user/
#
# And inspired Brad Turner's post:
# http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ilm2/thread/5db2707c-87c9-4bb2-a0eb-912363e2814a/

function get-sid
{
 PARAM ($DSIdentity)
 $ID = new-object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($DSIdentity)
 return $ID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier] ).toString()
}

$sid = get-sid $Principal

#DefaultLaunchPermission - Local Launch, Remote Launch, Local Activation, Remote Activation
$DCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission = "A;;CCDCLCSWRP;;;$sid"

#DefaultAccessPermision - Local Access, Remote Access
$DCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermision = "A;;CCDCLC;;;$sid"

#PartialMatch
$DCOMSDDLPartialMatch = "A;;\w+;;;$sid"

foreach ($strcomputer in $computers)
{
 write-host "`nWorking on $strcomputer with principal $Principal ($sid):"
 # Get the respective binary values of the DCOM registry entries
 $Reg = [WMIClass]"\\$strcomputer\root\default:StdRegProv"
 $DCOMDefaultLaunchPermission = $Reg.GetBinaryValue(2147483650,"software\microsoft\ole","DefaultLaunchPermission").uValue
 $DCOMDefaultAccessPermission = $Reg.GetBinaryValue(2147483650,"software\microsoft\ole","DefaultAccessPermission").uValue

 # Convert the current permissions to SDDL
 write-host "`tConverting current permissions to SDDL format..."
 $converter = new-object system.management.ManagementClass Win32_SecurityDescriptorHelper
 $CurrentDCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission = $converter.BinarySDToSDDL($DCOMDefaultLaunchPermission)
 $CurrentDCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermission = $converter.BinarySDToSDDL($DCOMDefaultAccessPermission)

 # Build the new permissions
 if (($CurrentDCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission.SDDL -match $DCOMSDDLPartialMatch) -and ($CurrentDCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission.SDDL -notmatch $DCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission))
 {
   $NewDCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission = $CurrentDCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission.SDDL -replace $DCOMSDDLPartialMatch, $DCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission
 }
 else
 {
   $NewDCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission = $CurrentDCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission.SDDL + "(" + $DCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission + ")"
 }

 if (($CurrentDCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermission.SDDL -match $DCOMSDDLPartialMatch) -and ($CurrentDCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermission.SDDL -notmatch $DCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermision))
 {
   $NewDCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermission = $CurrentDCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermission.SDDL -replace $DCOMSDDLPartialMatch, $DCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermision
 }
 else
 {
   $NewDCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermission = $CurrentDCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermission.SDDL + "(" + $DCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermision + ")"
 }

 # Convert SDDL back to Binary
 write-host "`tConverting SDDL back into binary form..."
 $DCOMbinarySDDefaultLaunchPermission = $converter.SDDLToBinarySD($NewDCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission)
 $DCOMconvertedPermissionDefaultLaunchPermission = ,$DCOMbinarySDDefaultLaunchPermission.BinarySD

 $DCOMbinarySDDefaultAccessPermission = $converter.SDDLToBinarySD($NewDCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermission)
 $DCOMconvertedPermissionsDefaultAccessPermission = ,$DCOMbinarySDDefaultAccessPermission.BinarySD

 # Apply the changes
 write-host "`tApplying changes..."
 if ($CurrentDCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission.SDDL -match $DCOMSDDLDefaultLaunchPermission)
 {
   write-host "`t`tCurrent DefaultLaunchPermission matches desired value."
 }
 else
 {
   $result = $Reg.SetBinaryValue(2147483650,"software\microsoft\ole","DefaultLaunchPermission", $DCOMbinarySDDefaultLaunchPermission.binarySD)
   if($result.ReturnValue='0'){write-host "  Applied DefaultLaunchPermission complete."}
 }

 if ($CurrentDCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermission.SDDL -match $DCOMSDDLDefaultAccessPermision)
 {
   write-host "`t`tCurrent DefaultAccessPermission matches desired value."
 }
 else
 {
   $result = $Reg.SetBinaryValue(2147483650,"software\microsoft\ole","DefaultAccessPermission", $DCOMbinarySDDefaultAccessPermission.binarySD)
   if($result.ReturnValue='0'){write-host "  Applied DefaultAccessPermission complete."}

 }
}
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 trap
 {
 $exMessage = $_.Exception.Message
 if($exMessage.StartsWith("L:"))
 {write-host "`n" $exMessage.substring(2) "`n" -foregroundcolor white -backgroundcolor darkblue}
 else {write-host "`nError: " $exMessage "`n" -foregroundcolor white -backgroundcolor darkred}
 Exit
 }
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and, I believe, it's because there's no equivalent 64-bit registry entry so PowerShell doesn't see it. Launching **mmc compexp.msc /32** and expanding **DCOM Config** seems to create the entry in the background.

The work-around is to manually add the 64-bit AppID yourself which is simply done by the following code,

```
$appGUID = 'YOUR_APPNAME_OR_GUID'

New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKCR -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
New-Item -Path HKCR:\AppID\$appGUID -Value $appGUID
#New-Item -Path HKCR:\Wow6432Node\AppID\$appGUID -Value $appGUID
Remove-PSDrive HKCR
```

I've left the 32-bit location in the above code too although that should already exist. Once you run the above then PowerShell should be able to see the COM component,

```
Get-WMIObject -query ('SELECT * FROM Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting WHERE AppID = "' + $appGUID + '"') -EnableAllPrivileges
```

Hope this helps someone as it was driving me bananas for hours!